# checkbox array html php

Tags: php, html, forms, web

I am having a lot of trouble getting a checkbox in a form to then pass to the .php file.. 
The html looks like

```
<td><label for="services">Services Requested:</label></td>
<td><form name="services" action="processForm.php" method="post">
          <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Massage" />Massage
          <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Facial" />Facial
          <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Manicure" />Manicure
          <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Pedicure" />Pedicure
          </form>
      </td></tr>
```

I am setting `$services = $_POST['services'];` right away in processForm.php. 
But this error which exists further down in processForm.php still comes up every time.

```
if(empty($services)) {
$errors[] = "You must choose at least one service.";
```

}

Comment: Try to do `var_dump($_POST)` or `var_dump($services)` to see what you get after submitting the form

Comment: Where's the submit button?

Comment: This is just one part of a large form, so the submit button is further down.

Comment: var_dump($services) returns string(0) ""

Comment: what about var_dump($_POST)?

Comment: var_dump($_POST) lists all my other variables and ["services"]=> string(0) ""

Answer (score 2):

Try change name of checkboxes. They have the same name as form

Answer (score 1):

The `submit` button just represents its `form` tag, so just to make sure, you didn't do something like this, did you?

```html
<form>
    <!-- HTML Tags -->
    <form name="services" action="form.php" method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Massage" />Massage
        <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Facial" />Facial
        <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Manicure" />Manicure
        <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Pedicure" />Pedicure
    </form>
    <!-- HTML Tags -->
    <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
</form>
```

If so, you shouldn't do that. Instead, create only one `form` tag that comprehends all fields!